# Combine Two commands

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have two commands the first command add a video on the another video 
here

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex 
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-8, scale=320x320[top];
[1:v]setpts=PTS-8, scale=320x320,format=yuva420p[bottom];
[top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1" 
-map 1:a -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

using above command i am getting out.mpg file to add watermark i am using below command

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" \
-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output23.mp4
```

now i want to combine this both command and wants to use as a single command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i source.mp4 -i overlay.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex 
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-8, scale=320x320[top];
[1:v]setpts=PTS-8, scale=320x320,format=yuva420p,colorkey=#000000:0.3:0.2[bottom];
[top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1[v];[v][2]overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'" 
-map 1:a -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```